# Calculating percent if column value is X

Tags: sql, percentage, calculation

I have a table with columns below:

- Cost
- Sales Channel
- Product Seller

I'd like to carry out a different calculation on cost, if certain values are met...

i.e.,

```
if Sales Channel = Mobile, and Product Seller = Mark, then take 8% off cost

if sales channel = desktop, and product seller = James, then take 5% off cost
```

I have tried:

```
select
channel,
acct_mgmr,
cost
(cost*0.05) as A
(cost*0.08) as B

from db.table
```

ideally, would be able to see a final sales price based on channel and sales manager...values to vary based on combination of columns

Comment: I don't understand a single thing. Please put some example data and show expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` to adapt the calculation for each use case :

```
SELECT
    channel,
    acct_mgmr,
    CASE
        WHEN ( Sales_Channel = 'Mobile' AND Product_Seller = 'Mark' )   THEN cost * 0.92
        WHEN ( Sales_Channel = 'desktop' AND Product_Seller = 'James')  THEN cost * 0.95
        ELSE cost 
    END as new_cost
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using a `CASE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Channel VARCHAR(255), acct_mgmr VARCHAR(255), cost INT)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('Mobile', 'Mark', 100)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('desktop', 'James', 200)

SELECT 
    channel,
    acct_mgmr,
    cost, 
    cost * (1 - CASE 
                    WHEN Channel = 'Mobile' AND acct_mgmr = 'Mark' THEN 0.08
                    WHEN Channel = 'Desktop' AND acct_mgmr = 'James' THEN 0.05
                END

    ) AS ModifiedCost
FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```